# Delete duplicate rows in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, duplicates

I have the same problem explained in the topic "Delete duplicate rows (don't delete all duplicate)". I wanted to comment it but i couldn't so I created a new question... sorry.

I've tried to do what Denis Valeev explained but in vain.

I tried this to delete the duplicates :

```
DELETE FROM controle 
WHERE id_controle NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(id_controle)
    FROM controle
    GROUP BY hash HAVING count(*) >= 1)
```

and I have :

```
ERROR:  column "hash" does not exist
LINE 5:   GROUP BY hash HAVING count(*) >= 1)
                   ^
********** Erreur **********

ERROR: column "hash" does not exist
État SQL :42703
Caractère : 125
```

I don't understand what is supposed to be the "hash" in spite of the explanations on http://www.siafoo.net/article/64

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You have to adapt the example given in the article to the actual structure of your table. Postgres is being very explicit in telling you the table doesn't have a column called "hash".

Comment: Thanks, I understood. But what I didn't understand was what I was supposed to write... But ok, I have it now... Thanks!